# ng-include doesn't seem to be requesting specified template for inclusion

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that I'm trying to get working with a Rails rest api. I am to the point where all the javascript seems to be loading without errors, but some templates don't seem to be included properly when I use ng-include. Here is an example:

```
<div ng-include="'<%= asset_path('header.tpl.html') %>'"></div>
```

When this section loads, I never see any attempt to load the specified template in the browser console. Any suggestions as to why the template isn't getting requested?

Comment: Do you see the exact same result even if you explicitly code the path (bypassing erb expansion)?

Comment: Open the Network tab in Chrome Dev tools and check if the partial gets loaded. Probably you'll get a 404. To what does <%= asset_path('header.tpl.html') %> translate? Are you sure this parses correctly

Comment: tosh, yes, I see the same behavior. asgoth, the partial actually gets loaded when I browse to it directly, but in the network tab it never even shows up. The partial is never requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting single quotes.

If you need to dynamically change what will be in the ng-include, try setting the value programmatically and then just pass that variable to the ng-include.

```
<div ng-include="templatePath"></div>

<script>$scope.templatePath = "header.tpl.html";</script>
```

Later in the code you can change the value of $scope.templatePath to whatever other file you need.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like an elegant approach regardless of my original problem. Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce the exact code state when I experienced this problem.